# word for chest/heart + throat

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word that describes the "core" of a person, their spiritual core, the place where their soul resides— these kinds of concepts.

It pertains to the heart and throat area of the body. Like you can feel an extreme emotion in your heart but often in reality it manifests itself in your throat.

This area of the body can easily be told apart from the rest of the body in orcas and frogs, because it is uniquely coloured. Lots of other animals also have some kind of separation of this area from the rest of their body, to varying degrees.

I think there is at least one loan word that describes this area of the body, ideally with these kinds of connotations.

Comment: Is there a term for this in your native language?

Comment: Another question about sympathetic and para-sympathetic nervous systems.

Comment: The word I use is the one you use: core

Comment: The location of the 'centre of being' varies from culture to culture. For instance the Ancient Egyptians considered it to be the heart, a belief that was adopted by the Ancient Greeks and, to some extent, by modern Europeans including the British and by extension, to Western culture in general. In China nd Japan, however, the Hara or Tanden is considered to be the centre of being in many ways. This is located in the lower abdomen, no higher than the navel.

Comment: @BoldBen do you know of any cultures where the centre of being is between the heart and the throat? or in the throat?

Comment: @theonlygusti No I don't. Given your question I assumed that you belonged to such  a culture.

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs here. I  +ed 1

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is **gut** as this meaning of the word makes it clear

> Innermost emotional or visceral response

*She felt in her gut that he was guilty.*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

> Gut feeling is actually aptly named, since within the intestinal lining is the enteric nervous system. This is where millions of neurons are hiding, and they "talk" to your brain via the vagus nerve. This nerve connects the abdomen (or your gut) to the brain's base and also travels through the chest (which is why "listen to your heart" is also truer than you think).

Comment: Gut has always meant to me the belly, far from the throat. Haven't seen it used in the way I want...

Comment: "Feeling something in your gut" is usually associated with the Solar Plexus, a large compex of nerves associated with the digestive system which is, in many ways, a second brain. It is located in the abdomen below both the throat and the thorax which are the sites mentioned in the question.

Comment: Guys...both things could be true, depending on the person.

Comment: The heart is the first organ to develop in a miniscule foetus and out of no-where tunes in to a synchronised, electrical, pulsed wave at just the right energy level, which, miraculously, causes the teen-weeny heart muscles to start pulsing: the heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

**Chakra**

noun: chakra; plural noun: **chakras**

```
(in Indian thought) each of seven centres of spiritual power in the human body.
```

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+chakra

Comment: Which chakra? And aren't the chakras literally _points_, in my knowledge they don't cover areas of the body...

Comment: To my knowledge the seven Chakras are likened to nodes, similar to a spiritual solar plexus for a specific area of the body, culimating in the crown node at the top of the head

Comment: They are thought to be spinning disks of energy that should stay “open” and aligned, as they correspond to bundles of nerves, major organs, and areas of our energetic body that affect our emotional and physical well-being.https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-solid-definition-of-half-filled-and-partially-filled-orbitals

Comment: The throat and heart chakras both occur in the region of the body I am talking about, so I don't think this is a correct answer

Comment: Core generally means somewhere in abdomen associated with a 'gut feeling' as mentioned elsewhere above. However, I'm aware that the Ancient Egyptians used to weigh the heart against the weight of a feather prior to deciding whether your soul was admissible to the afterlife (I think it was the afterlife - I may be wrong)